# Match Command in Qlikview

Tags: neo4j

I have created only one graph in Neo4j using the create statement. Now I want to retrieve data from the same graph using the MATCH command. It is giving me the correct count of all the nodes and relationships. Now I have run the same create query again without any changes and now if I retrieve the count using the same MATCH then I'm getting the double value.If run it again then triple value. If I give the return statement in the create statement then the count is correct, if I give it separately then the count is getting multiplied.

Why it is so.

And how to get the correct count if I run the same graph multiple times.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:D:\\Neo4j\\demo2dbcopy.csv" AS emp
MERGE (root:SubGraph {source: emp[7]})
MERGE (cname:Cmpname {name: emp[0]}) 
MERGE (clusters:ClustName { name: emp [1]}) 
MERGE (dom:domains { name: emp [2]}) 
MERGE (Hd:Head { name: emp [3]}) 
MERGE (DelHd:DeliveryHead { name: emp [4]}) 
MERGE (Mgr:Managers { name: emp [5]}) 
MERGE (Emp:Employees { name: emp [6]}) 
CREATE (root)<-[:PART_OF_SUB_GRAPH]-(cname)-[:has]->(clusters),(clusters)-[:contains]->(dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd),
      (Hd)-[:equals]->(DelHd),
      (DelHd)-[:assistedby]->(Mgr),
      (Mgr)-[:Dividesinto]->(Emp) 
return root,cname,clusters,dom,Hd,count(Hd);
```

and the MATCH statement is

```
MATCH (root:SubGraph {source: "demo2db"})<--(cname:Cmpname)-->(clusters:ClustName)-->(dom:domains {name:"BIDW"})<-[:headedby]-(Hd:Head) RETURN dom.name, count (Hd);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you must provide also both commands you are using - the create statement and also the match statement.

Answer (score 0):

The create command is

```
 LOAD CSV FROM "file:D:\\Neo4j\\demo2dbcopy.csv" AS emp
    MERGE (root:SubGraph {source: emp[7]})
    MERGE (cname:Cmpname {name: emp[0]}) 
    MERGE (clusters:ClustName { name: emp [1]}) 
    MERGE (dom:domains { name: emp [2]}) 
    MERGE (Hd:Head { name: emp [3]}) 
    MERGE (DelHd:DeliveryHead { name: emp [4]}) 
    MERGE (Mgr:Managers { name: emp [5]}) 
    MERGE (Emp:Employees { name: emp [6]}) 
    CREATE (root)<-[:PART_OF_SUB_GRAPH]-(cname)-[:has]->(clusters),(clusters)-[:contains]->(dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd),
   (Hd)-[:equals]->(DelHd),
          (DelHd)-[:assistedby]->(Mgr),
          (Mgr)-[:Dividesinto]->(Emp) 
    return root,cname,clusters,dom,Hd,count(Hd);
```

and the MATCH statement is

MATCH (root:SubGraph {source: "demo2db"})<--(cname:Cmpname)-->(clusters:ClustName)-->(dom:domains {name:"BIDW"})<-[:headedby]-(Hd:Head) RETURN  count (Hd);